# UITableView Restrictive Scrolling Around Sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I'm attempting to find a good way to restrict user scrolling around certain sections within my UITableView. For instance, when section 3 is selected (by my logic) I would like to have it locked at the top of the screen so you cannot scroll away from it until it is unlocked, but the important part is I still want to keep the responsive feel of the UIScrollView (ie. the bounce interactivity).

I attempted to recreate the logic on my own as seen below (which works pretty well, but doesn't have the same bounce feel I am looking for):

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let sectionRect = tableView.rectForSection(activeHeaderSection)
    let topY = sectionRect.origin.y
    let bottomY = topY + sectionRect.height
    let frameSize = self.tableView.frame.size.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height
    let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView)

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + frameSize > bottomY) && (frameSize < sectionRect.size.height) && (translation.y < 0) {
        UIView.animateLinear(0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0, animations: { self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.checkTuple[self.activeHeaderSection].pickChecks.count-1, inSection: self.activeHeaderSection), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: false) }, completion: nil)
    } else if (frameSize > sectionRect.size.height) || (scrollView.contentOffset.y < topY) {
        UIView.animateLinear(0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0, animations: { self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: self.activeHeaderSection), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false) }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So I did some searching around here and some question pointed towards restricting the scrollView's contentView height and position (ie. something like this) :

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var activeHeaderSection = 4
    let sectionRect = tableView.rectForSection(activeHeaderSection)

    tableView.contentOffset.y = sectionRect.origin.y // Set once when locked
    tableView.contentSize.height = sectionRect.size.height
    tableView.clipsToBounds = false
}
```

But this also isn't really giving me the behaviour I want as it always sticks to the top of my UITableView (with the correct height) but does not scroll down to the proper section. I'd prefer to use something simple like the second method if possible, I'm not sure if there is an even easier method for accomplishing something like this so I thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this

```
tableView.contentOffset.y = sectionRect.origin.y
tableView.contentSize.height = sectionRect.size.height
```

should be:

```
tableView.contentInset.top = -sectionRect.origin.y
tableView.contentSize.height = sectionRect.origin.y + sectionRect.size.height
```